# What are "zip" methods in Scala and Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Scala, Spark and a lot of other "big data"-type frameworks, languages, libraries I see methods named "`zip*`". For instance, in Scala, `List` types have an inherent `zipWithIndex` method that you can use like so:

```
val listOfNames : List[String] = getSomehow()
for((name,i) <- listOfNames.zipWithIndex) {
  println(s"Names #${i+1}: ${name}")
}
```

Similarly Spark has `RDD` methods like [`zip`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zip-org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD-scala.reflect.ClassTag-), [`zipPartitions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zipPartitions-org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD-boolean-scala.Function2-scala.reflect.ClassTag-scala.reflect.ClassTag-), etc.

But the method name "zip" is totally throwing me off. Is this a concept in computing or discrete math?! What's the motivation for all these methods with "*zip*" in their names?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are named zip because you are zipping two datasets like a zipper.

To visualize it, take two datasets:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

and then zip them together to get

```
   1 a
   2 b
   3 c
  4   d
 5     e
6       f
```

I put the extra spacing just give the zipper illusion as you move down the dataset :)

Comment: Oh nice, so its basically forming a 2-tuple where both elements are arrays with identical size as its output, makes sense! Thanks enormously!!!

Comment: Super demonstrative.

Comment: This is the best stack overflow comment ever!